# Spring Data Jpa - updating two entities together inserts new value

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

[image: Database Structure]

Whenever I try to update the Menu and Ingredients, it just inserts new values in database.

I checked and tried to update **only** the Menu entity and it worked.

Is there any "good way" to update multiple entity classes? (I checked and `Menu` and `ingredientName`, `ingredientDescription` do have predefined ID's when user goes to the update page)

Menu entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "menu")
public class Menu {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

      // Mapping To second table
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "menu_ingredient",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "menu_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ingredient_id"))
    private List<Ingredients> ingredient = new ArrayList<>();

    //getters / setters / constructors / tostring
```

Ingredients Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ingredients")
public class Ingredients {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "ingredient")
    private String ingredientName;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String ingredientDescription;
    //Getters/Setters/Constructors/ToString
```

Controller(Only Edit methods) :

```
@GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String edit(@PathVariable(name = "id")String id, Model model){
        Optional<Menu> menu = menuRepository.findById(id);

        List<Ingredients> ingredients = menu.get().getIngredient();

        for (Ingredients ing : ingredients){
            System.out.println(ing);
            // To Check data in the List , the output is : 
            // Ingredients{id=70, ingredientName='pizzaing1', ingredientDescription='pizzadesc1'}
        }

        model.addAttribute("ingredients", ingredients);
        model.addAttribute("newMenu",menu);


        return "edit-page";
    }

    @PostMapping("/postEditMenu")
    public String postEdit(@ModelAttribute("newMenu")Menu menu,
                           @RequestParam(name = "ingName")String ingName,
                           @RequestParam(name = "ingDesc")String ingDesc){



    String[] ingNameSplit = ingName.split(",");
    String[] ingDescSplit = ingDesc.split(",");

    for(int a = 0, b = 0; a<ingNameSplit.length; b++, a++){
        menu.getIngredient().add(new Ingredients(ingNameSplit[a], ingDescSplit[b]));
    }
        menuRepository.save(menu);

        return "redirect:/recipeList";
    }
```

Edit Page :

```
<form action = "#" th:action="@{/postEditMenu}" th:object="${newMenu}" method="post">
        <p>Menu Name: <br><input type="text" th:field="*{name}"></p>
        <div id="wrapper" th:each="ing: ${ingredients}">
            <label for="ingredientName"></label>
            <p>Ingredient Name: <br><input th:value="${ing.ingredientName}" id="ingredientName" type="text" name="ingName"></p>

            <label for="ingredientDescription"></label>
            <p>Ingredient Description:</p> <textarea id="ingredientDescription" type="text" th:text="${ing.ingredientDescription}" name="ingDesc"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>

        <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
        <br>

        <input type="submit" th:value="Submit">

    </form>
```

The `MenuRepository` just extends `JpaRepository<Menu,String>`

Comment: `new Ingredients(ingNameSplit[a], ingDescSplit[b]);` is this Ingredients entity? If so, new Ingredients will be saved into data base, since you are creating new entities.

Comment: Yes that is creating new Ingredients object. I was feeling something was wrong with this line of code . Any idea how to work around it ?

Comment: work around it? Do not create new entities if you want to update. I'm not sure I follow you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: And what's wrong with inserting new values? If you are creating new entities, they should be saved into data base.

Comment: I mean how to update both entities, Even if I delete that line of code and only leave `menuRepository.save(menu)` it still adds new element instead of updating it. The real brainwrecker for me is that it works fine if I only update "Menu" entity, but breaks when I add "Ingredient" as well